# Javascript exception in steeping thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting the following error in Jmeter while executing my test plan. Although it is not stopping the execution of the simulation in the log file I am getting a frequent error on this.

I have declared two user-defined variable called "***Default_Firm_AddOrder***" and "***Default_User_AddOrder***" and in the stepping thread group I am multiplying them to get the total number of thread by:

```
${__javaScript(${__P(Total_Firm_AddOrder,${Default_Firm_AddOrder})} * ${__P(Total_User_AddOrder,${Default_User_AddOrder})};)}
```

While executing, my execution is successful but I am getting the following error in the log file:

```
2019/08/14 01:56:34 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: C:\JMeter\OrderPlacer.jmx 
2019/08/14 01:56:35 ERROR - jmeter.functions.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript: [${Default_Firm_AddOrder} * ${Default_User_AddOrder};]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<cmd>#1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.error(DefaultErrorReporter.java:64)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:188)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:166)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:256)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:243)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:236)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.autoInsertSemicolon(Parser.java:1100)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1077)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:934)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:573)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:511)
```

I have added the image of my plan with the description as I didn't find any way to attach a file in SO.

[image: Test Plan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error can be overcome using 2 ways:

1. Using `__javaScript` function with groovy language processing
2. Using `__groovy` function for your evaluation

Example is shown below:

```
int result1 = ${__javaScript(${__P(Total_Firm_AddOrder,${Default_Firm_AddOrder})} * ${__P(Total_User_AddOrder,${Default_User_AddOrder})},)};
int result2 = ${__groovy(${__P(Total_Firm_AddOrder,${Default_Firm_AddOrder})} * ${__P(Total_User_AddOrder,${Default_User_AddOrder})},)};
log.info("Output1: "+ result1);
log.info("Output2: "+ result2);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `${__javaScript(${__P(Total_Firm_AddOrder,${Default_Firm_AddOrder})} * ${__P(Total_User_AddOrder,${Default_User_AddOrder})},)};` this worked with Java script but sure groovy will work as well.